# Onmouseover change color of table row

Tags: php, javascript, onmouseover

This is my table.

```
<?php 

while(($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))){
echo  '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo $result['serial'];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $result['address'];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<a href="profile-display.php?name='.$result['name'].'">'.$result['name'].'</a>' ;
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $result['postal'];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $result['website'];
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}

?>
```

Now I want that if a user moves his mouse over one row, the color should change.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Btw. the code would be much more readable and maintainable if you embed PHP into HTML and not vice versa.

Comment: Don't echo html, use a templating engine or just use <?=var?>. Your code is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to support IE 6, add this to your CSS:

```
table tr:hover {
    background:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `<tr>` tags `<tr onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#EABF4E';">`, or use `table tr:hover` in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit of a noob, but I think you need to give the table row a class, then give that class a hover property in your css file.

Add  a class to your table row like so:

```
echo  '<tr class="highlighter">';
```

You can name it anything, just make sure you use the same name in your css file.

Now, style the class so that it's color changes when a user's mouse hovers over it:

```
.highlighter:hover {
    background: #ffff99;
 }
```